# How to track the person talking webrtc in android?

Tags: detection, peer, speaker, webrtc-android

My problem is this.
I want to keep track of the time other people are talking on webrtc.

For example:
PeerA, PeerB and PeerC is in one room.
When peerA starts talking, I want to make any changes to the UI in PeerB and PeerC (for example, change border color of PeerA).

I can do this in js as follows.

```
this.interval = setInterval(() => {
 const peers = [...this.state.peers];
 this.state.peers.forEach(p => {
   const receiver = p.peerConnection
     .getReceivers()
     .find(r => r.track.kind === 'audio');
   if (!p.levels || !p.levels.length) {
     p.levels = [];
   }

   if (receiver && receiver.getSynchronizationSources) {
     const source = receiver.getSynchronizationSources()[0];
     if (source) {
       console.log(source.audioLevel);
       p.levels.push(source.audioLevel);
     }
     if (p.levels.length > 5) {
       p.levels.shift();
     } 
   }

   const sum = p.levels.reduce((prev, curr) => curr + prev, 0);
   p.isSpeaking = SPEAK_THRESHOLD < sum / 5;
 });
```

in Android PeerConnection object include
`private List<RtpReceiver> receivers;`
and RtpReceiver iclude

```
 public class RtpReceiver {
 private long nativeRtpReceiver;
 private long nativeObserver;
 @Nullable
 private MediaStreamTrack cachedTrack;
         .
         .
         .
```

I cant find  **getSynchronizationSources()** on [RtpReceiver](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/master/sdk/android/api/org/webrtc/RtpReceiver.java) or on [MediaStreamTrack](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/master/sdk/android/api/org/webrtc/MediaStreamTrack.java).
How can I get to getSynchronizationSources or is there any other way to meet this need?

**If there is no way to receive directly via RtpReceiver. What is the best way to do this?**

Comment: Did you find any solution for this ? If yes, can you please share the answer ?